# Can't access Windows 10 shares using SMB2 or 3 from 19.10

Tags: samba

My goal is to access windows administrative shares from Ubuntu 19.10.
This works perfectly fine if I enable SMBv1 on the Windows 10 machines. However I would like to use v2, at least.

What I have checked and done so far:

1. disabled back to default SMBv1 on Win 10
2. checked the SMB protocol version in Win 10: v2 is running
3. ran successfully the samba installation tutorial
   [Install and Configure Samba](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-samba#0)
4. i can access the Ununtu shares from Win 10 just fine
5. added to the smb.conf file:

`client min protocol = SMB2
client max protocol = SMB3`

was this part even needed?

6. I tried both by IP and hostname: none work

P.S. Workgroup is "WORKGROUP"

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, you should add this:

```
[global]
    client min protocol = SMB3
    client max protocol = SMB3
```

In windows 10 you should edit this and enter in the Local Group Policy Editor (search in windows)

> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> Lanman Workstation -> Enable Insecure Guest Logon - Enabled

Answer (score 0):

To get some insight into what may be occurring, try installing smbclient:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install smbclient
```

Then try connecting to see if you receive any error messages which can give some insight into this issue (replace the items in the brackets with the appropriate details):

```
smbclient //<IP or hostname>/<share> -U <connection user>
```

Comment: `smbclient is already the newest version (2:4.10.7+dfsg-0ubuntu2.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
`

Comment: owever, weirdly, now it works but only if I enter the entire path :)

Instead of entering in the GUI just `smb://hostname` and having displayed **all** admin shares, now it only works if I enter the entire path `smb://hostname/D$`

Comment: That's normal because you need a specific target when mounting SMB shares.

Comment: But then why does it work with SMB v1?